# how to calculate time to next minute in r

Tags: r, time

I have a data frame below:

```
dput(d)
structure(list(t1 = c("09:45", "10:37"), t2 = c("10:24:00", 
"10:40:00"), t3 = c("10:55:00", "11:03:00"), t4 = c(0, 
0)), row.names = c(19L, 23L), class = "data.frame")
```

**t4** column is the next time column.Initially it has zero values. I have to calculate the **t4** column as follows :

If **t1** has new row as **10:45**, t4 column of first value should be

```
10:55 - 10.45 =9 min
```

Initially it assign 9 min then 8 min,7 min,6 min,5 min,4 min,3 min,2 min,1 min,0. i.e. I have to loop through each minute until it comes to 10:55  so that it assign zero value to **t4** when it comes to **10:55**(10:55 is from t3 column).

I have generated sequence of minutes also.

```
dput(head(seqMinute_new))
structure(list(seqMinute = c("2019-01-16 07:00:00", "2019-01-16 07:01:00", 
"2019-01-16 07:02:00", "2019-01-16 07:03:00", "2019-01-16 07:04:00", 
"2019-01-16 07:05:00")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

How to achieve that. suggest me to how to do that.

Comment: the expected output seems to be diferent from 'd'.  Is there a typo `If t1 has new row as 10:45` i.e. is it `t2`

Comment: Does `t4` should be similar to a vector of the form `9:0` ? How do you calculate t2 and t3 in function of t4 and t1 ?

Comment: Also, `t1` is `09:45`

Comment: @akrun, It is from t1 only. That is new entry of t1 column.

Comment: Based on your dput, it would be 10:55 - 9:45 = 1hr 9 min

Comment: @dc37, t1, t2, t3 are different time columns

Comment: @Magie If the difference of 10:55 - 9:45 in minutes is 69 minutes, then do you expect 0 to replicate 69 times

Comment: @akrun, No we have to calculate t4 column based on new entry t1 column as mentioned above. ``` 10.55 - 10:45 = 9 min```.

Comment: @Magie can you please check your input data, I don't see `10:45`

Comment: It is from  another table for explain i have added to this ```dput(d)```.

Comment: May be there is a confusion here.  If I understand from your descriiption, the values in 't1' showed in the 'd' are not to be used. and when it gets updated with a new row i.e. `"10:45"`, it needs the calculation.  Can we know how this is getting updated?  Is it in a loop?

Comment: @akrun, Am i confusing you still?

Comment: Yes, there is confusion.  `library(data.table);c(rev(seq_len(as.numeric(as.ITime(d$t3[1])  - as.ITime(str_c("10:45", ":00")))/60 - 1)), 0)#
 [1] 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0`

Comment: The confusion is  how the new values are updated.  Based on that, solutions could change

Comment: 10:45 value from another table column. To explain it simple i have added that column to ```d```

Comment: Can we put it ina for loop?

Comment: @Magie May be this helps `library(data.table);library(dplyr);library(tidyr);library(purrr); d %>% mutate(t4 =  map(as.numeric(as.ITime(t3)  - as.ITime(str_c(t1, ":00")))/60 - 1,  ~ seq_len(.x) %>% rev %>% c(., 0))) %>% unnest(t4)`